care of or care for
Which one of the below is correct?

The involvement of fathers in the care for their newborn baby is beneficial.

or

The involvement of fathers in the care of their newborn baby is beneficial.

Most grammar tools suggest the second one is correct. Why is that?
Why is it that both "take care of their newborn baby" and "care(verb) for their newborn baby" are correct, but at the same time, the care(noun) for their newborn baby is incorrect?

"In the care" has no verb. Besides that, it's colloquial which is right. Verb: "When fathers care for their newborn baby in daily nurturing, diapering, and holding, that care is beneficial.

Look at Ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+care+for+their+child%2Cthe+care+of+their+child&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 . Though this is not the full phrase, "the care of their child" is far more common.

The second one is correct because care as a noun is normally followed by of, but as a verb by for.

The expectant parents were taught about the care of a newborn baby.
The new parents were taught how to care for their baby.

